# How can I make a constant string available to my code and a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid, datacontext

I have a Window with a DataGrid in it.  My DataGrid handles the BeginningEdit event.  I want to run some code that possibly cancels the BeginningEdit event based on the name of the column.  For example:

```
private void tickerGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = (string)e.Column.Header != "Name";
}
```

My DataGridTemplateColumn tag looks like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="False">
```

I would like to store "Name" as a constant somewhere.  How can I do this?  I tried making a public String property and binding the DataGridTemplateColumn Header like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Path=ColName}" IsReadOnly="False">
```

but I think the DataContext is different because this didn't work for me.

How can I make a constant string that is available both to my C# code and to a DataGridTemplateColumn Header?

Comment: Just try this one `Header="{x:Static yourNamespace:Constants.ColName}"` - as per @mathieu 's answer

Comment: Actually your solution worked for me.  I couldn't get @mathieu 's answer to work for me.  I think your solution worked because of the `.ColName` in your answer.

Comment: glad it did - I'll post and answer for others / clarity - and you decide which one to award (he can edit his too) - I don't care much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this one (posting based on our previous discussion)...

`Header="{x:Static yourNamespace:Constants.ColName}"`

(And `Constants.ColName` is based on @mathieu 's answer - just define a class with a static property anywhere in the code - and get the namespace right)

Basically you don't need `Binding` as what you have is a const string so simplest thing is just using `x:Static`.  (and you can add properties like that where needed).

Alternative is also to 'construct' a string object in XAML somewhere and using `StaticResources` to that. But this seems easier - you can keep a global static class for similar things.

Answer (score 1):

Create a static class

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string ColName = "ColName";
}
```

Add a namespace reference on top of your xaml file :

```
xmlns:customNamespace="clr-namespace:Namespace.Of.Your.Constants.Class"
```

Add your binding :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Path=ColName, Source={x:Static customNamespace:Constants}" IsReadOnly="False">
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. I put in `xmlns:customNamespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"` and a simple textbox  `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ColName, Source={x:Static customNamespace:Constants}}" />`. When I try this, I get an error message that says "'customNamespace:Constants' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name."